# RStudio Server does not use the buff/cache memory

Tags: r, linux, ram, rstudio-server

I am loading some large .csv files on an RStudio server which require circa 73gb. The server is a `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS` with 125GB RAM, so theoretically I should be able to load more data on RAM and do computations which require more RAM. However, RStudio Server denies that with the following error message:

"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.9 Gb".

Looking into the `free -mh` it seems that there is `available` memory of 42GB, but RStudio does not utilise it.

```
~:$ free -mh

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         81G        1.2G         28M         43G         42G
Swap:          979M        4.0M        975M`
```

Why is this happening and how can I utilise these 42GB for computations?

`top` output:

```
top - 11:05:58 up 21:19,  1 user,  load average: 0.24, 0.22, 0.22
Tasks: 307 total,   1 running, 201 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.6 us,  0.2 sy,  0.1 ni, 99.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13170917+total,  1216824 free, 85389312 used, 45103040 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1003516 total,   999420 free,     4096 used. 45033504 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 4292 user1     30  10   39956   5052   4272 S   2.6  0.0   0:06.94 galaxy
 1171 root      20   0  488892  44216   7540 S   1.3  0.0  12:24.39 cbdaemon
 5998 user1     20   0   44428   3936   3168 R   1.0  0.0   0:00.07 top
 6153 user1     20   0  275740 101112  29396 S   0.7  0.1  25:55.97 nxagent
 1207 root      20   0  377116 163944  68132 S   0.3  0.1   5:37.13 evl_manager
 1247 root      20   0 1262092  63308  14956 S   0.3  0.0   0:35.77 mcollectived
 6623 user1     20   0  126640   5852   3212 S   0.3  0.0   0:02.48 sshd
 7413 user1     20   0 80.623g 0.078t  53712 S   0.3 63.8  20:14.46 rsession
    1 root      20   0  225756   8928   6320 S   0.0  0.0   0:23.05 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 kthreadd

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, the problem was not on the OS or R/RStudio Sever, but instead on the use of `data.table`, which I used to open the .csv files. Apparently, it prevented the system from using the available memory. Once I moved to `dplyr`, I had no problem utilising all the memory the system has.